# Angular 2 sibling components 2 way binding

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services

I am having 2 sibling components displayed at the same time to the user. One of them is a QuestionList which takes an array of questions from service and display list of questions. Once you click on a particular question it displays (next to the list) question details like seen below [image]

Question detail component uses router to take question id from the URL and stores it in a separate variable called selectedQuestion like this:

```
selectedQuestion: Question;
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: any) => {
        this.questionIndex = params['questionId'];
        this.selectedQuestion = this.qs.getQuestion(this.questionIndex);
      }
      );
  }
```

In the template selectedQuestion is binded using [(ngModel)] -> 2 way data binding so I can update the question by simply sending selectedQuestion to the service.

**I am struggling to understand why and how Angular2 updates the list when I change something in the question detail view?** I thought cause I have created separate variable called selectedQuestion, list on the left should not be updated till I push changes to using the service? My understanding of using ngModel is that it should 2 way bind to selectedQuestion only and definitely not update my service

Comment: checkout my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are refering to same instances of the selected question and you need to modify as below

Import the lodash, if you dont have install using

```
npm install --save lodash

import * as _ from "lodash";


selectedQuestion: Question;
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: any) => {
        this.questionIndex = params['questionId'];
        this.selectedQuestion = _.clone(this.qs.getQuestion(this.questionIndex));
      }
      );
  }
```

Alternatively,

```
selectedQuestion: Question;
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: any) => {
        this.questionIndex = params['questionId'];
        let jsonQuestionasString JSON.stringify(this.qs.getQuestion(this.questionIndex);
       this.selectedQuestion = JSON.parse(jsonQuestionasString);
      });
  }
```

There are a several alternatives to it. few of which is shown above

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While I am sure your solution works (really appreciate it) I am still not sure why is it the same instance, as it'd seem that I assign it in separate classes to a new instance, and given that array of Questions lives in the service and is being only accessed from those 2 classes and passed to new variables one would expect that it'd be a separate copy?

Comment: In javascript, though there are two separate objects, they both point to same instance(same memory reference). So in order to separate the references you should be doing any of the above options.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I need to look more into memory management then!

Comment: You will get it by practice.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are sharing the same instance of question between two components, during change detection both components detect changes and they both get updated.