# Angular2 the same name on different components

Tags: angular

I opened two instances of my app in a browser and noticed that when I modify a field in one panel it is reflected in the second though it is a different page and managed by different *.component.ts file. Is it a Angular2 bug or feature? I'm using Final version. Moreover, when I submit a form on the second page, the first page submitted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 sibling components 2 way binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317036/angular-2-sibling-components-2-way-binding)

Comment: thanks, I don't share any state and work with different entities. Only name of form components is the same on html templates

Comment: did u read my explanation in that post?

Comment: yes, if you are telling that this is a feature and I need to use some external library, I think this is not good as something not predictable and should be treated as an angular2 bug

Comment: **I need to use some external library** what do you mean by this? and can you elaborate your problem?

Comment: Did you make a mistake with a reference to the page in the comment above or you proposing npm install --save lodash?

Comment: **when I modify a field in one panel it is reflected in the second** your question has the answer in above referenced post.